# Advanced filtering "show items when value is 0" results in (blank) - how to replace it with 0?

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a card, that shows the COUNT of service requests, which consists of "opened" requests and "closed" requests. So in this case, there are 2 requests in total whereas 2 are in status "open" and 0 "closed":

[image]

The value comes from column "SR Number"

[image]

The setting in power bi is:
"PKT" with value SR Number is filtered by column "hierarchy"
"open" with value SR Number is filterd by column "hierarchy" AND column "request status" as filter (NEW)
"closed" with value SR Number is filtered by column "hierarchy" AND SHOULD BE fed by "request status" as filer (CLOSED) BUT THERE ISN'T ANY

[image]

When I set the advanced filter I get (blank) as value.

[image]

I now know that this is Power Bi default behaviour and I read some articles on how to replace it with 0. Some recommend a new measure or adding DAX code.

I tried both but still don't get it solved, respectively don't get it at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add new Measure:

`PKT Count Formatted = FORMAT(COUNT('Table'[PKT]), "0")`

And use it as a field in the viz